# Tabs in eclipse becoming invisible

Tags: eclipse

When using Eclipse (Kepler, on Windows 7 64 bit) from time to time some of the open tabs... disappear. **The tab bar is still there, but some tabs just go blank. When I mouse over them tho, they come back and become fully visible.**

So this is not a functional problem, just an aesthetic one, but it's really disturbing not to be able to see what tabs are open. **Does anyone know how to stop this behavior?**

It happens often, but is not prompted by anyhing I do, so I cannot recreate it at will. To further clarify what it looks like, I put together this image in Paint.net:

[image: image that shows clearly what my problem is]

Thank you in advance.

//LJ

**Edit:**

I found out what's prompting this behavior. When I build and run the project, the console pops up, then after closing the window, the console automatically hides again, but the tabs it was covering are blank. However, as stated earlier, they do come back if I hover over them. However, I still do not know how to fix this. Here is a gif composed of screenshots showing this behavior in-action:

[image]

Comment: Had this issue with Eclipse Mars.2 and it still there in Eclipse Neon it is very annoying.

Comment: same issue in 2019-12 !

Answer (score 9):

I was also seeing this. Here's my specific situation. I'm running Eclipse Oxygen on Windows 10. For my external monitor, I went into display settings and set 'Change the size of text, apps, and other items' to 125%. This caused the application to render text awkwardly. I then right-clicked on the desktop shortcut and selected Properties. Under the Compatability tab, I enabled the 'Override high DPI scaling behavior', and I selected 'Scaling performed by: System (Enhanced)'.

This configuration caused me to experience the behaviour that you reported.

Altering the selection of 'Scaling performed by' to System fixed my issue.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Just wanted to comment that this answer worked for me. For more details: I'm also using Eclipse Oxygen on Windows 10. I did not change the size of text, but I did set the 'Scaling Performed by: System (Enhanced)' like this answer suggested. The problem has not shown up since then.

Comment: I'm using Eclipse 4.23 on Windows 10 and the exact opposite solved my issue. I disabled 'Override high DPI scaling behaviour' and the issue disappeared. Thanks a lot for the hint!

Answer (score 3):

I've successfully fixed that on a UHD monitor by selecting the Classic Theme under Preferences -> General -> Appearance.
It is still (not) working as described in the question with the Light Theme.

Using Spring Tool Suite, Version: 3.9.4.RELEASE (Eclipse Oxygen.3a (4.7.3a))

Answer (score 2):

Try this:
Go to Window->Preferences. Go to General->Appearance. Change theme here and restart eclipse. 
Also try [increasing heap size](http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_increase_the_heap_size_available_to_Eclipse%3F) for eclipse.e

## Edit

Its is difficult for me to reproduce your problem on my machine.
However you can try these

1. Try using the [eclipse theme plugin](http://eclipsecolorthemes.org/?view=plugin) and change themes and check.
2. I guess first part of the problem occurs on eclipse start-up if so that means the editor plugin is loading still. Try changing plugins loading order on eclipse start-up in Window-Preferences. General->Startup-Shutdownload.You can disable least used or all. Restart eclipse.
3. As explained in second part. Console is showing up and closing automatically. Have a close look on the second picture, When your application window is opened Console view shorts button is enabled in Fast view bar. After you click close button console view disappears because console view is opened **AS FAST VIEW**.
   So before launching your application. Make sure that console view is **visible** to you. So Click on **restore** button on the FAST VIEW BAR where console view is there(i.e in the second picture right most side bottom FAST VIEW BAR)
4. If your eclipse application depends on many plugins then you have to increase heap size for your application and assign start up levels for plugins. Go to run configuration of your eclipse application add parameter to increase heap size in **Arguments** tab and assign start up levels for plugins in **Plugins** tab. For more info look at eclipse Help content.

Comment: Good idea, but sadly it did not work. First tried to just change the theme, then I did increase the heap size, then I tried increasing it even more (512M to be precise), but there was no improvement. Also, I was using a built-in stanard theme from the start, not something I had downloaded.

Comment: This must be a bug of the theme. I tried everything, only changing the theme from dark to default "fixed" the problem. Funny fact: dark theme worked perfectly for so long time and suddenly yesterday it stopped working.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue with my Eclipse Jee 2018-09 on Windows 10.
To fix this issue try the following steps:
**right click on eclipse icon -> Compatibility -> Change High DPI settings**
[image: Make sure the settings are all unselected as shown in the below screenshot.]

Restart eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue when I have switched back from an installed custom dark theme on **Eclipse Mars.2 Release (4.5.2)**, So here is how I have fixed it:

> go to Window->Preferences->Appearance then change theme to different
>   them than classic (Dark in my case) then select the classic again.

Answer (score 0):

I switched to Classic Theme in Preferences->Appearance->Theme-> Classic Theme
and every thing is working fine for me.

Also u can change these settings in eclipse configuration file..
Paste these lines there.

```
-Dswt.enable.autoScale=true
-Dswt.autoScale=150
-Dswt.autoScale.method=nearest
```